# Integrating custom module with odoo website

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, qweb

I have a custom module called admission form with some fields suppose name, phone, email, etc. how to add this form to website module using templatr to work like contact form in contact us page when filled data is automatically created in new leads. instead of leads i want it to transfer the information to my custom module.

Summary: instruction to relate website to custom module.

```
class AdmissionForm(models.Model):
     _name = 'admission.form'


     name = fields.Char()
     phone = fields.Integer()
     email = fields.Char()
     faculty = field.Many2one('res.faculty')
```

Answer (score 1):

In ODOO Whenever  you want to performe  some task at the time of **creation**  ,then you must `override  create method` in your model (:admission.form).

Let say you want to create a partner just after creation  of the record in admission.form model then follow these steps:

1. Override `create`  method .
2. Call the `super` with the argument and hold it value in result.
3. Now do your task  .
4. return `result`.

Code snippet:

```
    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
    result = super(AdmissionForm, self).create(vals)
    new_vals = dict(name=result.name,
                    phone=result.phone,
                    email=result.email,
                    is_company=1,
                    supplier=1,
                    customer=1,
                    )
    self.env['res.partner'].create(new_vals)
    return result
```

In case if you want to do some task before creation of record then follow these steps:

1. Override create  method .
2. Do your task .
3. Call the `super` with the argument and `return` it.

   ```
   @api.model
   def create(self, vals):
   new_vals = dict(name=vals.get('name'),
                   phone=vals.get('phone'),
                   email=vals.get('email'),
                   is_company=1,
                   supplier=1,
                   customer=1,
                   )
   partner=self.env['res.partner'].create(new_vals)
   return super(AdmissionForm, self).create(vals)
   ```

Comment: @parakash sorry i edit my question but dont know why it revert back to old one. I want to add a form in website just like contact form in contact us page. When customer fill the form new lead is auto created

Comment: so create a template , put the form in side and  set the url of your controller where you want to handle the data , Now on the controller you can access the model by request.env['admission.form']  ,

Comment: Sounds logic parakash! Can u please show me an examplr i never used controller, it can be very simple just name field will work fine. Thanks in advance

Comment: try this link https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/addons/website_sale/controllers/main.py

Comment: Prakash checked the linked got very confused. I dont know how controller work. I am saying if you could post a simple one here just pass the name field from website to module

Comment: just visit https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/addons/website_sale/views/templates.xml#L68   for form xml  and https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/addons/website_sale/controllers/main.py#L359  for controller

Comment: hi @Omeed hope your query has been resolved  after visiting the  previously shared link [about  form xml and controller action ]